# Router Switch hanged down

Tags: networking, switch, hub

I have a switch placed in department and connected through Media Converter which is directly connected through optical fiber cable from 3com Switch.

Now the issue is Some times suddenly the Endpoint Switch hangs and its LED blinks very slowly, and 5 desktop systems there lose their connectivity with the Server.

Any way or solution to solve/resolve this issue????

Switch has 16ports.

Comment: Buy a new switch with a fiber trunk port, toss the media converter.

Comment: I have tried to improve the English in your post. But I think the question probably still needs more details. For instance: Which LED is blinking? On what switch? What is the model of the other switch, and all of the other devices involved? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If its an unmamaged switch and it stops working pretty much all you can do is replace it and see if that fixes the problem.

I would recommend getting a switch that has at least one SFP port so you can eliminate the media adapter and plug the fibre directly into the switch.